# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null

Tags: nativescript

You are using the deprecated nsconfig.json file. Just be aware that NativeScript 7 has an improved nativescript.config.(js|ts) file for when you're ready to upgrade this project.
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null

Comment: welcome to SO. Please, try to format your question before posting and to describe what is the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Because can't find template path.

```
ns create ProjectName --template @nativescript/TemplateName
```

Example :

```
ns create HelloWorld --template @nativescript/template-blank 
ns create HelloWorld --template @nativescript/template-blank-ts 
ns create HelloWorld --template @nativescript/template-blank-ng
```